# Regression in R -- 4 features, 4 million instances

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a text file in the form ( User Id, Movie Id, Ratings, Time) and I want to do a vanilla regression on the dataset .( Just 4 features, >4 million instances)

```
model <- glm ( UserId ~ MovieId+Ratings+Time,data=<name>)
```

It gave an error :

```
ERROR: cannot allocate 138.5MB vector .
```

The size of the file is just 93MB.  How do I do regression with R and  not have memory problems ? Should I store the data differently ?

Thanks .

Some more info : Working on a linux box with 3GB of RAM. I have googled around but most links I have got talk about datasets which are generally > RAM, which in my case is not true :( ( just 93MB) .

Comment: I suspect some posters can answer your question in more depth, but the [Revolution R blog](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/04/new-functions-for-linear-model-inference-in-4-3.html) has some posts detailing their package/product working with similarly large data.

Comment: The implementation of regression may need several copies of the data in memory at some time, so this is not uncommon. You should read `?Memory` for some pointers on how to manage/monitor memory usage (particularly on windows boxes).

Comment: Thanks.  I will wait for someone to answer then :) . Thanks, i will look into that.

Comment: @crazyaboutliv : You should also take into account that with so many instances, you can get huge model matrices that have to reside in your memory as well. The underlying matrix calculations can become quite quickly memory-intensive.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember this from next time :)

Comment: Note that if MovieId is a factor (which it should be for the regression to make sense), then the number of features is actually very large, with one column for each movie because MovieId will be dummy coded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`biglm`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html) is a package specifically designed for fitting regression models to large data sets.

It works by processing the data block-by-block. The amount of memory it requires is a function of the number of variables, but is not a function of the number of observations.

Comment: I am just in the process of installing that :) . Thanks .I did not do it till now because I thought big datasets == huge size, which in my case is not true. But I guess small size files with too many observations also cause trouble.

Comment: @crazyaboutliv: Your dataset isn't too big. It is unclear to me why it would cause memory problems. Since yours is a vanilla linear regression problem, have you tried `lm` instead of `glm`?

Comment: biglm took care of this and trained the model pretty fast. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

The model matrix required has the same number of rows as your data, but the number of columns in it is roughly the number of unique strings (factor levels)!

So if you have 1000 movies that will generate roughly a 4e6x1000 matrix of doubles. That's around 32 GB...

You can try to generate the model matrix separately like this:

```
# Sample of 100 rows, 10 users, 20 movies
d <- data.frame(UserId = rep(paste('U', 10), each=10),
                MovieId=sample(paste('M', 1:20), 100, replace=T),
                Ratings=runif(100), Time=runif(100, 45, 180))
dim(d) # 100 x 4
m <- model.matrix(~ MovieId+Ratings+Time, data=d)
dim(m) # 100 x 21
```

Comment: Yeah , I realized it later.  biglm took care of it, but, I think the model is overfitting . Need to go for a regularizer

Answer (score 1):

That R error message doesn't refer to the total amount of memory, but to the last chunk R tried to allocate and failed on. You may want to try profiling the memory usage ([Monitor memory usage in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856306/monitor-memory-usage-in-r)) to see what's really going on.