# Get each line of code in a code chunk to be shown in the 'R Markdown' window as it is executed

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

When knitting an R markdown file, I often find myself staring at the Markdown output waiting for a chunk to finish. Unfortunately, I don't know of any way of seeing what command that chunk is currently executing. This would be handy to get a sense of the progress, or to find performance bottlenecks.

Is there some knitr option I have missed ? Setting `progress=TRUE, verbose=TRUE` just shows the chunk code before that chunk is executed. I want each line of code to be shown in the console just after/before it is executed, just like in an interactive session.

Answer (score 2):

Next to *Console tab* at the bottom, you will see *R Markdown* tab, all steps can be seen there, see screenshot below:

[image]

**EDIT 1:** We need to set up global options `opts_knit$set(progress = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)`

Example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(progress = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple ...


```{r SummaryCars}
summary(cars)
```
````

Output on *R Markdown* window:

```
processing file: temppp.Rmd
  |................                                                 |  25%
  ordinary text without R code

  |................................                                 |  50%
label: global_options (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.................................................                |  75%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: SummaryCars
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ R code chunk ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
   summary(cars) 
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
##------ Fri Jul 17 09:00:42 2015 ------##


output file: temppp.knit.md
```

**EDIT 2:** This answer doesn't meet OP's requirement, keeping this answer as an example to illustrate OP's code.

Comment: I was aware of the fact that the R Markdown window shows which chunks are being processed together with a global percentage. However, I would like to know which lines are being processed *within* these chunks. Just as you would see if you were running these commands in an interactive session.

Comment: See above again, lines after EDIT section: it is showing which ones are running: see `summary(cars)`?

Comment: Setting those options just spits out the entire code (here it is one line, but usually there are several) before executing the chunk. What I want is for every line to be shown in the output as it is executed, just like in an interactive session. I'll edit my question because it doesn't seem very clear now.

Comment: opts_knit$set(progress = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)  - Dosent solve the Issue

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a solution … **but**: Use it with extreme caution. It messes around with the source code prior to evaluation. Besides, it clutters the output document with diagnostic output. However, for debugging purposes, it might be very useful.

---

## Introduction

As I understand it, the progress window for the knitting process in RStudio cannot be used to log the evaluation progress of a chunk because any chunk output (like `message`s) is only show after the whole chunk has been evaluated. Therefore, the only feasible workaround is writing the progress to a file.

## The right hook

So the solution will be to write some diagnostic message like "Now evaluating `[code]`" to a file, expression by expression. Unfortunately, there is no default knitr [hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) for "call `FUN` before each expression". All the code in a chunk (at least all the code that is to be evaluated) is passed to `evaluate::evaluate` in `block_exec` (see [line 172 in `block.R`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/16ee84a6060e55e9821ac4922b866cf2992194b1/R/block.R#L172)).

As knitr never iterates over a chunk's code expression by expression, there is no natural way place to implant the logic that writes diagnostic messages. (I didn't delve deeper into `evaluate`; maybe such an iteration takes place somewhere therein.) However, the chunk's source code can be manipulated *before* it is passed to `evaluate` at once.

Note that when a chunk is run, its source code is available as value of the [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options) `code`. The structure is a character vector, each element representing one line. Manipulating `code` allows to modify the source code such that it writes the diagnostic messages on its own while being evaluated.

## The logging function

I will use the following small helper function to write the logfile:

```
writeLog <- function(message, file = paste0(current_input(), ".log"), sep = "\n") {
  cat(paste(message, sep), file = file, append = TRUE)
}
```

The file name of the logfile will be `[documentname].log`, e.g. `mydocument.Rmd.log`. As `writeLog` always appends to an existing file, the following line can be used to purge (erase and recreate) the logfile for each compilation:

```
if(file.exists(logfile <- paste0(current_input(), ".log"))) { file.remove(logfile) }
```

A potentially useful extensions of `writeLog` could use `gc()` to [monitor the memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856306/monitor-memory-usage-in-r).

## Modifying the source

The basic idea is to add something like

```
writeLog(sprintf("%s - Now evaluating the following expression: ", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), sep = NULL)
writeLog('summary(cars)')
```

before each expression (in the example above: before `summary(cars)`). The problem is, where exactly should the call to `writeLog` be located? This is not an issue with code containing exactly one (complete) expression each line, but it *is* problematic in the following case:

```
summary( # Here some descriptives:
  cars
)
```

For a chunk with that code, `code` will be a vector with three elements:

```
print(code)
[1] "summary( # Here some descriptives:" "  cars"                             ")"
```

Simply injecting `writeLog` calls after each element is *not* a good idea … Therefore, and this is where the solution becomes somewhat nasty, `code` needs to be `parse`d first. With the argument `keep.source = FALSE`, all comments, formattings etc. will be removed and we get "clean" expressions.

Before each of these expressions, a `writeLog` call can be inserted. This new code replaces the original code using an [option hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#option_hooks) that I called `log`:

```
opts_hooks$set(log = function(options) {
    parsed <- parse(text = options$code, keep.source = FALSE)
    newCode <- sapply(as.character(parsed), function(x) {
      return(c(
        'writeLog(sprintf("%s - Now evaluating the following expression: ", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), sep = NULL)',
        sprintf("writeLog('%s')", x),
        x))
    })

    options$code = as.vector(newCode)
  return(options)
})
```

## Results

Starting with the following chunk

````
```{r, log = TRUE}  
summary( # Here some descriptives
  cars
)
Sys.sleep(5)   
print("foo")
```
````

the source code becomes

```
writeLog(sprintf("%s - Now evaluating the following expression: ", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), sep = NULL)
writeLog('summary(cars)')
summary(cars)
writeLog(sprintf("%s - Now evaluating the following expression: ", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), sep = NULL)
writeLog('Sys.sleep(5)')
Sys.sleep(5)
writeLog(sprintf("%s - Now evaluating the following expression: ", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), sep = NULL)
writeLog('print("foo")')
print("foo")
```

which produces the following logfile:

```
2016-03-04 12:08:05 - Now evaluating the following expression:  summary(cars) 
2016-03-04 12:08:05 - Now evaluating the following expression:  Sys.sleep(5) 
2016-03-04 12:08:10 - Now evaluating the following expression:  print("foo")
```

## Using the logfile

As the purpose of the logfile is to reflect the progress *during* the knitting process, it is important to open it without blocking further write operations on it. Ideally, we even want to see update of the file.

On Windows, for example Notepad++ opens files in a non-blocking way and has an option to [autoreload modified files](https://superuser.com/a/274965/491805). On Linux, `tail -f [documentname].log` [should do the trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154605/open-a-text-file-and-let-it-update-itself).

## Limitations and caveats

The main limitation relates to the source code that is visible in the output document if `echo = TRUE`: It is polluted by the `writeLog` calls. Moreover, all comments as well as identations are lost and the syntax is "standardized" (e.g., `print('x')` becomes `print("x")`). So far, I've found no good solution for this – only a partial one:

- Add `options$codeBackup <- options$code` as the first line in the `log` option hook.
- Use the [output hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks) `source` and replace the argument `x` (the source code that will be printed) by `options$codeBackup`:

  ```
  hook_source <- knit_hooks$get("source")
  knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
   return(hook_source(options$codeBackup, options))
  })
  ```
- Problem: Works only with `results = "keep"` or chunks where the only output occurs at the end. Otherwise, the *complete* code will be repeated whenever a *part* of the code should be printed.

Besides, manipulating the source code might be dangerous. As `parse` is a base R function, I wouldn't expect the parsing itself to be problematic. However, I am not sure about the conversion to character afterwards.

Of even more concern is the insertion of function calls into the original source. Per se, `writeLog` is quite innovent and should not interfere with the following code. But you never know. Imagine a piece of code that generates a list of all files in the current working directory (first expression) and relies on this list to be accurate in the second expression. Suddenly, creating the logfile inbetween is not so innocent anymore … (even though the true problem in this example goes back to an [TOCTTOU issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) in the original code).

The bottom line is: Don't use this code "in production" but only for debugging purposes.

## Full code / Example

````
---
title: "Log evaluation of chunks line by line"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(knitr)

if(file.exists(logfile <- paste0(current_input(), ".log"))) { file.remove(logfile) }

# Caution: This will DELETE "file.log"!
writeLog <- function(message, file = paste0(current_input(), ".log"), sep = "\n") {
  cat(paste(message, sep), file = file, append = TRUE)
}

opts_hooks$set(log = function(options) {
    #options$codeBackup <- options$code # extension: use codeBackup in source hook to replace parsed code
    parsed <- parse(text = options$code, keep.source = FALSE)
    newCode <- sapply(as.character(parsed), function(x) {
      return(c(
        'writeLog(sprintf("%s - Now evaluating the following expression: ", format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), sep = NULL)',
        sprintf("writeLog('%s')", x),
        x))
    })

    options$code = as.vector(newCode)
  return(options)
})


# hook_source <- knit_hooks$get("source")
# knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
#   return(hook_source(options$codeBackup, options))
# })
```

```{r, log = TRUE}
summary( # Here some descriptives
  cars
  )
Sys.sleep(5)
print("foo")
```
````