# Measure peak memory usage in R

Tags: r, performance, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I want to measure my peak memory usage in R so that I can allocate resources appropriately. **The method must include intermediate objects created during the analysis**. For example, `mx` is a 80-Mb object created on every loop of `lapply` but never saved as a global variable. The peak memory usage should be at least 80Mb above baseline.

```
gc(reset = TRUE)
sum(gc()[, "(Mb)"]) # 172Mb

lapply(1:3, function(x) {
  mx <- rnorm(1e7) # 80Mb object
  mean(mx)
})

sum(gc()[, "(Mb)"]) # still 172Mb!
```

Comment: what platform are you on? you can monitor memory usage on Linux with a bunch of tools

Comment: I'm using RStudio on a Mac

Comment: Ultimate way is to use OS tools for that. In R C you can either R_alloc or malloc, latter one is not being tracked by R.

Comment: @jangorecki that might be what I'm looking for, I'll do some research

Comment: Have a look at [Monitor memory usage in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7856306/10488504]).

Comment: Maybe see also [How to Monitor Your Mac's Memory Usage](https://www.macinstruct.com/node/423).

Comment: @qwr what would I use to monitor peak memory usage in Linux?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in the `peakRAM` package. From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/peakRAM/index.html):

> This package makes it easy to monitor the total and peak RAM used so that developers can quickly identify and eliminate RAM hungry code.

```
mem <- peakRAM({
  for(i in 1:5) {
    mean(rnorm(1e7))
  }
})
mem$Peak_RAM_Used_MiB # 10000486MiB
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `gc` function for that.

Indeed, the **`gc` function** provides the current and maximum memory used within the fields 11 and 12 (in `Mb` regarding the documentation, but obviously in `Mio` in practice on my machine). You can reset the maximum value with the parameter **`reset=TRUE`**. Here is an example:

```
> gc(reset=TRUE)
         used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 318687 17.1     654385   35.0   318687 17.1
Vcells 629952  4.9  397615688 3033.6   629952  4.9
> a = runif(1024*1024*64)  # Should request 512 Mio to the GC (on my machine)
> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   318677  17.1     654385   35.0   318834  17.1
Vcells 67738785 516.9  318092551 2426.9 67739236 516.9
> memInfo <- gc()
> memInfo[11]              # Maximum Ncells
[1] 17.1
> memInfo[12]              # Maximum Vcells
[1] 516.9
> rm(a)                    # `a` can be removed by the GC from this point
> gc(reset=TRUE)           # Order to reset the GC infos including the maximum
         used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 318858 17.1     654385   35.0   318858 17.1
Vcells 630322  4.9  162863387 1242.6   630322  4.9
> memInfo <- gc()
> memInfo[11]
[1] 17.1
> memInfo[12]              # The maximum has been correctly reset
[1] 4.9
```

In this example we can see that up to `516.9 - 4.9 = 512 Mb` has been allocated by the GC between the two gc calls surrounding the `runif` call (which is consistent with the expected result).

Comment: Actually I don't think this method accounts for intermediate values in functions and apply loops, see my new test above

Comment: Does it take into account memory that is not managed by gc? Like malloc rather than R_alloc?

Comment: @jangorecki No, memory allocated with `malloc` should not be seen by the GC as it is not explicitly requested to do so. However, AFAIK most R library persistent objects are not allocated using a plain `malloc` because object are not collected (unless at exit time or manually by the user). Note that it may change in future release of R as the version 4.0 seems to experiments with reference counting.

Answer (score 5):

The object returned by `lapply` weights only 488 bytes because it's summarized  : garbage collection has deleted the intermediate objects after mean calculation.
`help('Memory')` gives useful information on how R manages memory.
In particular, you can use `object.size()` to follow-up size of individual objects, and `memory.size()` to know how much total memory is used at each step :

```
# With mean calculation
gc(reset = T)
#>          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#> Ncells 405777 21.7     831300 44.4   405777 21.7
#> Vcells 730597  5.6    8388608 64.0   730597  5.6
sum(gc()[, "(Mb)"]) 
#> [1] 27.3

l<-lapply(1:3, function(x) {
  mx <- replicate(10, rnorm(1e6)) # 80Mb object
  mean(mx)
  print(paste('Memory used:',memory.size()))
})
#> [1] "Memory used: 271.04"
#> [1] "Memory used: 272.26"
#> [1] "Memory used: 272.26"

object.size(l)
#> 488 bytes


## Without mean calculation :
gc(reset = T)
#>          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used (Mb)
#> Ncells 464759 24.9     831300  44.4   464759 24.9
#> Vcells 864034  6.6   29994700 228.9   864034  6.6
gcinfo(T)
#> [1] FALSE
sum(gc()[, "(Mb)"]) 
#> [1] 31.5
l<-lapply(1:4, function(x) {
  mx <- replicate(10, rnorm(1e6))
  print(paste('New object size:',object.size(mx)))
  print(paste('Memory used:',memory.size()))
  mx
})
#> [1] "New object size: 80000216"
#> [1] "Memory used: 272.27"
#> [1] "New object size: 80000216"
#> [1] "Memory used: 348.58"
#> [1] "New object size: 80000216"
#> [1] "Memory used: 424.89"
#> [1] "New object size: 80000216"
#> [1] "Memory used: 501.21"

object.size(l)
#> 320000944 bytes
sum(gc()[, "(Mb)"]) 
#> [1] 336.7
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If instead of returning `mean` you return the whole object, the increase in memory use is significant.

Comment: Is there a method for monitoring memory usage that accounts for garbage collection? Maybe something external to RStudio?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `help('Memory')`.To supervise current memory use you can print `memory.size`, see my edit