# What is the most memory efficient way to append items to an existing list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list in R, `my_list2` in the example below.

I want to add items to the list in a way that minimises the peak RAM usage.

Is there a more memory efficient way to do this than using the `append` function?

I'm aware that it's best practice to create an 'empty' list then fill it as per `my_list2` in the example below, but this isn't an option as the list already exists.

```
# If I could create the list from scratch I'd do it list this:
my_list <- vector('list', 10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  my_list[[i]] <- i
}

# Is there a better way than the 'append' function?
my_list2 <- list(1)
for (i in 2:10) {
  my_list2 <- append(my_list2, i)
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to extend `my_list` with more overhead than you need, and then chop it down afterwards if you didn't use the pre-allocated space?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, are you able to provide an example of how I could do this in a memory efficient way?

Comment: Something like: `length(my_list) <- 100` then loop and do the `my_list[[i]] <- i` loop, then `my_list[sapply(my_list, Negate(is.null))]` afterwards. I'm not sure about the memory implications, hence the comment, not an answer.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the elaboration/example.

Comment: @thelatemail You don't really need to pre-allocate lists. List elements need much more memory than the list itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `append()` in each iteration, you could create a temporary list and append it to `my_list2` only once at the end. Would this do the job for you?

Here's an example with 5k iterations in the `for` loop:

```r
my_list <- list(1)
my_list2 <- list(1)

bench::mark(
  orig = {
    for (i in 2:5000) {
      my_list <- append(my_list, i)
    }
    my_list
  },
  mine = {
    tmp <- vector("list", 4999)
    for (i in 1:4999) {
      tmp[[i]] <- i + 1
    }
    append(my_list2, tmp)
  },
  iterations = 10
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 orig       420.01ms    1.69s     0.567    95.7MB     13.6
#> 2 mine         1.52ms      2ms   406.       96.8KB      0
```

Note that `bench::mark()` automatically checks that both codes give the same output.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not familiar with bench::mark but I'm assuming mem_alloc is tracking memory? And assuming so is it fair to say that while your code is much faster the two approaches have similar memory? I need to reduce memory usage rather than improve speed (although faster run time would also be helpful)

Comment: Yes `mem_alloc` tracks memory. Note that my way is 1000x more memory efficient (`MB` in your case, `KB` in mine)

Comment: I missed the difference in units! That's great, accepting your answer now...

Comment: yeah, watch out for the different units in the columns - why I never use bench::mark

Comment: The column *mem_alloc* gives how much memory is allocated but at the same time also memory is set to not used and freed stochastic by `gc`. With this I think it is not possible to show which method is better in **peak RAM usage**.

Answer (score 1):

A practical solution with low peak RAM usage can look like:

```
my_list <- list(1)
N <- length(my_list)
length(my_list) <- N + 9
for (i in 2:10) {
  my_list[[N + i -1]] <- i
  #gc() #Optional
}
```

You can use `gc` to get the **peak RAM usage**. But this is much influenced whether there was a garbage collection or not during execution. To see the minimum possible peak `gctorture` could be turned on, but then the execution time gets typical much slower. As the result could be influenced by the order how the methods are called I start each time a new vanilla session.

```
#Using append
n <- 1e5
gctorture(on=TRUE)

set.seed(0)
L <- list(sample(n))
gc(reset=TRUE)
#         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 285638 15.3     664228 35.5   285638 15.3
#Vcells 633121  4.9    8388608 64.0   633121  4.9
for (i in 2:10) L <- append(L, list(sample(n)))
gc()
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells  344156 18.4     664228 35.5   345174 18.5
#Vcells 1215086  9.3    8388608 64.0  1265554  9.7
```

```
#Using [[<-
n <- 1e5
gctorture(on=TRUE)

set.seed(0)
L <- list(sample(n))
gc(reset=TRUE)
#         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 285638 15.3     664228 35.5   285638 15.3
#Vcells 633121  4.9    8388608 64.0   633121  4.9
for (i in 2:10) L[[length(L)+1]] <- sample(n)
gc()
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells  346937 18.6     664228 35.5   347919 18.6
#Vcells 1221639  9.4    8388608 64.0  1272088  9.8
```

```
#Using [[<- but resizing the list before
n <- 1e5
gctorture(on=TRUE)

set.seed(0)
L <- list(sample(n))
gc(reset=TRUE)
#         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 285638 15.3     664228 35.5   285638 15.3
#Vcells 633121  4.9    8388608 64.0   633121  4.9
N <- length(L)
length(L) <- N + 9
for (i in 2:10) L[[N - 1 + i]] <- sample(n)
gc()
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells  346564 18.6     664228 35.5   347498 18.6
#Vcells 1220761  9.4    8388608 64.0  1271479  9.8
```

Here `append` needs 8.0 Mb and `[[<-` 8.2 Mb independent if the list size is increased before or not.

---

Doing the same but without `gctorture` but manually using `gc` after each step gives:

```
#Using append
n <- 1e5

set.seed(0)
L <- list(sample(n))
gc(reset=TRUE)
#         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 285638 15.3     664228 35.5   285638 15.3
#Vcells 633121  4.9    8388608 64.0   633121  4.9
for (i in 2:10) {L <- append(L, list(sample(n))); gc()}
gc()
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells  344145 18.4     664228 35.5   372952 20.0
#Vcells 1215054  9.3    8388608 64.0  1319826 10.1
```

```
#Using [[<-
n <- 1e5

set.seed(0)
L <- list(sample(n))
gc(reset=TRUE)
#         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 285638 15.3     664228 35.5   285638 15.3
#Vcells 633121  4.9    8388608 64.0   633121  4.9
for (i in 2:10) {L[[length(L)+1]] <- sample(n); gc()}
gc()
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells  346926 18.6     664228 35.5   377474 20.2
#Vcells 1221607  9.4    8388608 64.0  1352555 10.4
```

```
n <- 1e5

set.seed(0)
L <- list(sample(n))
gc(reset=TRUE)
#         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 285638 15.3     664228 35.5   285638 15.3
#Vcells 633121  4.9    8388608 64.0   633121  4.9
N <- length(L)
length(L) <- N + 9
for (i in 2:10) {L[[N - 1 + i]] <- sample(n); gc()}
gc()
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells  347659 18.6     664771 35.6   374526 20.1
#Vcells 1223042  9.4    8388608 64.0  1273592  9.8
```

Here `append` needs 9.9 Mb, `[[<-` without resizing the list in advance 10.4 Mb and when the list size is increased before 9.7 Mb.

---

In case you want to know the total amount of allocated but maybe in the meantime also freed memory or other options have a look at [Monitor memory usage in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856306).